# How to fire a trigger on multile tables?

Tags: sql-server

Does any know whether it is possible to create one trigger on multiple tables. What I mean to say is :

Assume ther are 3 tables X, Y, Z.
I want to insert a row into the table A for any UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE action on any of the X, Y, Z tables.

Comment: Fairly often, if someone wants to work with two or more tables in the *same* way, it's an indication that it should in fact be a *single* table with additional column(s) that encode the information currently embedded in those table *names*. Are you sure you're not in a situation like that?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make each trigger per table like so, no other solution:

```
   CREATE TRIGGER trig_X_changes
           ON X
           FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

   CREATE TRIGGER trig_Y_changes
           ON Y
           FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create one trigger on three different tables, but if you want to consolidate your code, you could put your trigger code (the insert into table A) into a stored procedure, and create a trigger on each X Y & Z table that just calls the stored procedure.

Note that if your stored proc code needs access to the inserted or deleted tables, you'll need to pass them as parameters to the stored proc from the trigger.